# Why is my override method not being called in C++?

Tags: c++, overriding, c++17

So I have a base class that is made to hold a string value, and be able to add characters onto it:

```
class TextInput
{
public:
    std::string value;
    void add(char c) 
    {
        if (!value.empty()) 
        {
            value += c;
        }
        else
        {
            value = c;
        }
    }

    std::string getValue() 
    {
        return value; 
    }
};
```

Then an inherited class, which is the same as parent but should only allow you to add numeric values to the string:

```
class NumericInput : public TextInput 
{
public:
    TextInput input;
    void add(char c)
    {
        if (isdigit(c)) 
        {
            input.add(c);
        }
    }

    std::string getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
};
```

What I want to know is, when called like this in my tests:

```
#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    TextInput* input = new NumericInput();
    input->add('1');
    input->add('a');
    input->add('0');
    std::cout << input->getValue();
}
#endif
```

Why does the call to add still only use the base add class? I would assume this to use the child NumericInout class since it is being created as one, but when debugging it still only uses the parent class and I don't understand why?

Comment: There's nothing overridden in the shown code. If you open your C++ textbook to the chapter that explains virtual functions you will learn the proper way to override functions in the base class.

Comment: @Sam the child `add()` is overriding the base `add()`, isn't it?

Comment: No it doesn't. C++ does not work this way. C++ is not Java. Something else must be done in order for it to actually override it. See your C++ textbook for more information.

Comment: [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) can be helpful as well.

Comment: You need to make `add` `virtual` in the base class. Using `override` is fashionable (helps robustness), but is not necessary. C++ ain't Java you know: classes are not polymorphic by default. Also having `TextInput input;` as a member of the child class, whilst that is a useful *pattern* occasionally, is most likely an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class NumericInput : public TextInput 
{
public:
    TextInput input;
```

This is almost *definitely* not what you want. If you're inheriting, I can't think of a good reason you'd *ever* also want composition. Get rid of this `input` member variable. When you inherit, you already get everything from the parent class (including `value` in this case).

To specifically call the parent class's `add()`, you can do `TextInput::add()`, so your child add could look like:

```
void add(char c)
{
    if (isdigit(c)) 
    {
        TextInput::add(c); // Call parent add()
    }
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to call `add()` on a `TextInput` pointer that's pointing to a `NumericInput`, and you want it to resolve to call the `NumericInput`'s `add()`, you must declare the base `add()` to be `virtual`:

```
virtual void add(char c) { // ...
```

Lastly, you can still append to a string even if there's nothing in it, so your check in the base `add()` does nothing.

Altogether, that'll make your code look like:

```
class TextInput
{
public:
    std::string value;
    virtual void add(char c)  { value += c; }
    std::string getValue() { return value; }
};

class NumericInput : public TextInput 
{
public:
    void add(char c)
    {
        if (isdigit(c)) { TextInput::add(c); }
    }

    // You already get this for free from the inheritance
    // std::string getValue()
    // {
    //     return value;
    // }
};
```

Live example here: https://ideone.com/kQxAPo

Comment: Add the override keyword to add.  May as well teach good habits.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: I'm feeling very pedantic today: `override` is an identifier with special meaning, not a keyword. Nice answer though, +1.

Comment: @bash it is a contextual keyword, more colloquially and clearly.  Identifier with special meaning is standardese, and sometimes standardese isn't useful to talk.to humans with.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: I only really mention it since you can still use `override` as a class name, function name, or variable name. Its introduction didn't break existing code. (cf. decltype).

Comment: Thanks so much! Kind of learning this on the fly from a C# background. I appreciate the detailed answer!